# SSRS report parameters on drill through report

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, drilldown

I'm having trouble getting values to work when I use the drill through.

I have a main report which I have selected a text box to access my 2nd report (drill through).

When I get to the 2nd report it is asking me to choose the values I want from the 2 parameters at the top.

I have used expressions on my main report, so when I access the drill through I would like it to automatically choose 'Monday' etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create drill through, don't forget to do the parameter mappings. 
Then add the same name parameters in drill through report.
[image]